# Copy the most recently updated cells from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I need to update every day with some stats: every day I type a new number into the cell below the last one. I want to be able to display on a 2nd sheet in the same workbook, only the most recent 6 entries.

So I want Sheet 2 to always contain only the last 6 cells from Sheet 1 and for it to update whenever I put each day's figures into Sheet 1.

At the moment I've got half way I think, where onEdit I copy specific cells from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 but as I add a new figure every day, that's no good. I'm specifying static cells in my script, and that's wrong: I need the script to only pick up the most recent 6 cells.

Can't seem to find any answer on the forums so any help gratefully received. My code so far:

```
function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15ih18G5WCnmPTwo1SCSj0tvw0ZVyi-hXUP4qrFyQOi4"); 
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Most Recent");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("C10:C15");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("B5:B10");
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":G"+(last_row+1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below copies the bottom six cells from Sheet1 into Sheet2 on every edit event in Sheet1

```
 function onEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (origin.getName() == "Sheet1") { 
    var r = origin.getActiveCell();
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numberOfCol = 3;
    if( row > 1) { 
      var numberOfRows = row >= 7 ? 6 : row - 1;
      var startRow = row >= 7 ? row - numberOfRows + 1 : 2;
      range = origin.getRange(startRow, 3, numberOfRows, numberOfCol);
      range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, numberOfCol, 1, numberOfRows);
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: Please review your code:  condition on r.getRow  should at least be >6 and you inverted columns and rows in copyValues (1116 instead of normally 1161).

Comment: r.getRow() referred to two header rows, not to the actual content. Assumption was that the OP is not starting afresh, so case when the row number was less than 6 + number of header rows was not covered. Updated my answer to include this corner case too.  Rows and column are not inverted - copying works as expected.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the confusion on range, this is a method I never use...about all other methods use row-col-nofrow-nocol sequence, therefore my mistake. Anyway, your code is more clear now, thanks.